# How to use xml2json in Ionic2 project

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am developing a mobile app using Ionic2 framework. I need to convert a xml file to json format.

For this I have installed "xml2json" using command "npm install xml2json --save".

This has saved a module named "xml2json" in "node_modules" folder.

I can also see it under dependencies in "package.json" file as "xml2json": "^0.9.1"

Now when I declared it in the .ts file as "import * as xml2json from "xml2json";", I am receiving the following error: "can not find module xml2json"

I guess I need to install the typings for this module. I have tried all the possible typings commands but could not install it. I received errors like

**typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/xml2json/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200**

Please let me know how can I install typings for xml2json OR how can I use xml2json in my project. Thanks.

My system information:

typings version - 1.3.2

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.36
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
Node Version: v6.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can. 
Just add your `node_modules/path_to_xml2json.js` to your index.html and declare it in your component : `declare var xml2json: any;`

It's not a typescript module, so you can import it like you did.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the typings for xml2json now using the command

typings install xml2json --save

Answer (score 0):

For Parsing xml to json in ionic 2 You can install the typings for xml2json now using the command

```
typings install xml2json --save
```

If it generate error like this

```
'typings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Then first use this command to install typing

```
npm install typings -g
```

Then run previous command

```
typings install xml2json --save
```

Then it'll work fine. Hope it work for you